# Result set not ordered after union

Tags: mysql

Since mysql did not have a full join, I used left join, right join followed by a union, I got the result that I wanted.  However, the order of the result was not what I expected.  The following is result after union..

```
version   Seg       field_num   version   Seg       field_num
2.6       ACC       1           2.3       ACC       1
2.6       ACC       2           2.3       ACC       2
2.6       ACC       3           2.3       ACC       3
2.6       ACC       4           2.3       ACC       4
2.6       ACC       5           2.3       ACC       5
2.6       ACC       6           2.3       ACC       6
2.6       ACC       7           null      null      null
2.6       ACC       8           null      null      null
2.6       UB1       1           2.3       UB1       1
2.6       UB1       2           2.3       UB1       2
2.6       UB1       3           2.3       UB1       3
2.6       UB2       1           2.3       UB2       1
2.6       UB2       2           2.3       UB2       2
2.6       UB2       3           2.3       UB2       3
null      null      null        2.3       UB1       4
```

The problem is the last row fall out of order of other "UB1" in the result set. This result set also contain duplicated columns for comparison purpose.  Sor I did not know how to order this result set by using "columns".  I have tried many different ways to try to make the result set ordered but with no success.  Do you have any suggestions of how to get this result set ordered?

Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Just add an `ORDER BY` clause... what am I missing?  Show your query

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesize the individual queries and add an order by.

```
   (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
    UNION
    (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
    ORDER BY a;
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is a and B in this query according to the context?

Comment: I reluctant to go back changing the query I have.  Is it possible to "order" the end result set?

Comment: I would order by a.SEG and b.SEG. The a refers to table a or table 1, the b refers to table b or table 2 these are just alias for temporary join condition, they are not distinct to the table they are pulling from generic alias.

Comment: I used the following query as suggested.  (select * from mytable as t1

where t1.A_version = 2.6) union

(select * from mytable as t2

where t2. T_verison = '2.3')

order by A_Seg, T_Seg    But got an error..  "Can't reopen table: 't1'"  Was this query legal?

Comment: Specify the individual column names in the select statements rather than the '*'

Comment: I revised the query to ..                                                (select t1.A_Seg from mytable as t1

where t1.A_version = 2.6)

union

(select t2.T_Seg from mytable as t2

where t2.T_verison = '2.3')

order by A_Seg, T_Seg
But still got the error...

Comment: you can not use tablename.column like that.  I'm not sure why you are aliasing the tablename at all in the individual queries, but the columns certainly need a common alias name.  (select A_Seg as Seg FROM mytable where ...) UNION (select T_Seq as Seg FROM mytable where..) ORDER BY Seg

Comment: Thanks for being so patient!!! I am new to mySql and not really know all the syntax well.   I change my query to                                      (select A_Seg as Seg from mytable 

where A_version = 2.6)

union

(select T_Seg As Seg from mytable

where T_version = '2.3');                                            But I still get the error of can't reopen table:'mytable'  Any idea what is wrong with this one?